# What is “localcomputer” or domain and how to get it?

Tags: windows, sql-server, azure, windows-10, windows-home-server

I am trying to install a program (Microsoft SQL Data Sync Agent), and in one step it is asking me the following:

Enter the account you want to run Windows Service under. E.g. domain\user. localcomputer\localuser. The account must have network access to reach Microsoft SQL Data Sync Service through your network's proxy. User name: "I have to insert something here" password "this is another entry"

I don't quite get what they are asking me for, I guess the user name is the domain\user that they mentioned, but how can I get that information?

Thank you so much for your time, I hope you have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

The sync agent needs to run as a Windows service, so it is asking you to specify the user that the service should run under. This needs to be a user that already exists either on the machine you are installing or on your domain. I would suggest asking your IT team for details on how you should run this, as usually this would want to be a service account, rather than running as a specific user.